# Trying to connect to Heroku: MongoParseError: URI malformedm cannot be parsed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, heroku-cli

I'm trying to post my app to Heroku for class and it keeps crashing. This is the error code I'm receiving. I'm not exactly sure what's happening, the H10 error is a blanket statement, maybe someone here could shed some light. This is what I'm getting when using heroku logs --tail.
Edit: My app works totally fine on my local machine, I'm only getting this error when trying to post to Heroku

```
2022-02-13T18:27:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nmendez6594@gmail.com
2022-02-13T18:27:38.841499+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user nmendez6594@gmail.com
2022-02-13T18:27:38.841499+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7d112609 by user nmendez6594@gmail.com
2022-02-13T18:27:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-02-13T18:27:39.104174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-13T18:27:40.901836+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-13T18:27:42.058731+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-13T18:27:42.058745+00:00 app[web.1]: > budget-app@1.0.0 start
2022-02-13T18:27:42.058746+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-02-13T18:27:42.058746+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-13T18:27:42.395832+00:00 app[web.1]: App running on port 55680!
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401378+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:580
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401379+00:00 app[web.1]: return callback(new MongoParseError('URI malformed, cannot be parsed'));
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401380+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401380+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401381+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:580:21)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401381+00:00 app[web.1]: at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:283:3)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401382+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:284:5
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401382+00:00 app[web.1]: at maybePromise (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:692:3)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401382+00:00 app[web.1]: at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:280:10)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401382+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:836:12
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401383+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401383+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:832:19)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401384+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401384+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401384+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401384+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401384+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:19:10)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.401385+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-02-13T18:27:42.521294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-13T18:27:42.598710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-13T18:27:48.281004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=budget-app-pwa4.herokuapp.com request_id=5de2651b-5f3f-4a1e-84f2-18c0123b8dd7 fwd="32.215.142.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-13T18:27:49.746492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=budget-app-pwa4.herokuapp.com request_id=f15d0dc1-7a19-49e1-a743-13f31cac6c31 fwd="32.215.142.46" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const logger = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const compression = require("compression");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/budget";

const app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// routes
app.use(require("./routes/api.js"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: How did you provision MongoDB? Have you looked at the value of `MONGODB_URI` to see what it contains?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: (a) Where does `MONGODB_URI` come from? Are you using [an addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores)? Are you using Atlas? Something else? (b) Does it appear to have been set properly?

Comment: Yes I'm using atlas, this is starter code that was given to us prior to beginning this homework. I've already connected atlas to the database, the issue is the connection while posting on heroku

Comment: Atlas won't set `MONGODB_URI` for you. How did you configure it on Heroku?

Comment: I added it via  -heroku config:set MONGODB_URI="mongodb+srv://yourUsername:yourPassword@yourClusterName.n9z04.mongodb.net/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority"- (this is example code from mongo)  it's even in the config vars on my heroku page

Comment: Okay, well MongoDB doesn't like that value for some reason. Do you have special characters in your password? If so, did you encode them?

Comment: I had mixed up my mongoDB user/password with the actual database user/password. That was my issue

Comment: Strange that that would cause a "malformed URL" error. I suspect your MongoDB password has special characters that would need to be percent-encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you everyone for helping. My issue was that I was using my Mongo username/password login info in the URI string, instead of my Mongo database username/password combination. I'm not sure if that makes any sense but I have it up and running. Thank you again!

Comment: You mean your credentials for the mongodb.com site instead of the ones for a user on your database instance? Regardless, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Yes that exactly! I'm glad I figured it out as well, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at your log file, you can see that the top of the stack (at the point in which the exception is thrown) points to a *parseConnectionString* call. As you most likely deduced (since you included this in your title), the line above is a big clue as to what is going on:

> MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed

This indicates an issue with the connection string you are providing to the *mongoose.connect* function. Given the code you have shared, this can only be the result of an invalid *process.env.MONGODB_URI* value or the fallback *mongodb://localhost/budget*. Depending on how the MongoDB instance was provisioned, I might lean towards checking the value of the environment variable first, but if you are unsure about this, it might be best to first determine which of the two values your application is using (i.e., you could log this).

Overall, the issue appears to be related to the connection string you are using to connect to the MongoDB instance, and not explicitly caused by an issue with your application.